# Automatic parsing of data in R

Tags: r, io, readline, readlines, import-from-csv

I am wondering if there is a package/function dedicated to the automatic guessing the file structure, e.g. `.csv` file, space or tab delimited etc.

What I'm thinking is to automatically infer `character delimiter` (e.g. tab, space, comma), `header` (yes/no), `quote` (yes/no), `number of lines to skips`,  and `comment.char`.

Surely this would mean one extra pass through the file, but if it can guarantee that it will infer correctly it would be nice.

Has there been any attempt?

Comment: And I understand people will be skeptical, talking about exceptions. I am quite certain it will be possible to figure it out perfectly (perhaps using probabilistic reasoning).

Comment: Take a look at `fread` from `data.table`. But I think this question will be cloased since it is asking for a tool not a real question.

Comment: @agstudy Wow, that's great. Saves me a lot of trouble :-). Do you use it yourself and does it work for all/most situations?

Comment: @agstudy If I would reframe it such as "How can I read in the data automatically?" would it then be a good question?

Comment: Not it is not agood question:) A good one is like : I have tried this (for example you show some code using `fread`) , but it don't work in this situation? why ? ( I think you know all the story of a reproducible example)..

Answer (score 2):

See `fread` in the [data.table package](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/) or `reader` in the [reader package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/reader/index.html).